# Java keyword this in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

First day learning Objective-C but have a java background. I'd like to use the same variable name for my parameter that I do for my instance variable. In java we do it like this

```
public class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String age;

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void setAge(String age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

In objective c so far I have this

```
@interface Person : NSObject
{
    int age;
    int name;
}
    -(void) setAge:(int) age;
    -(void) setName:(int) name;
    -(int) getAge;
    -(int) getName;
@end

@implementation Person
-(void) setName:(int) w
{
    weight = w;
}
-(void) setAge:(int) a
{
    age = a;
}
-(int) getName
{
    return name;
}
-(int) getAge
{
    return age;
}
@end
```

Comment: you need to rehprase this a bit so it actually sounds like a question

Comment: Do you mean like `self`? It refers to the current instance but both are structured quite differently

Comment: self is giving me an error. "local declaration of age is hiding instance variable"

Comment: Initialize them as `@property`'s of Person and use `@synthesize` to create the getter and setter for the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C, you can define your own accessors or use `@syntehsize` to create them automatically for you.

In the case where you want to define accessors manually, setters are declared like this:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name {

    self.name = name;
}

- (void)setAge:(NSInteger)age {

    self.age = age;
}
```

For getters, you simply declare them as follows:

```
- (NSString *)name {

    return self.name;
}

- (NSInteger)age {

    return self.age;
}
```

Comment: What does this NS stuff mean? Totally foreign to me as a Java guy. How is NSInteger different from int?

Comment: NS is just a prefix used in Cocoa's Foundation. The asterisk means you're declaring a pointer. Java handles pointers automatically. With any C language, you have to handle that yourself. Objective-C is no exception. Basically, anything that is not a primitive type needs to be declared as a pointer.

Comment: So NSInteger is a primitive type and NSString is an object type?

Comment: and how is NSInteger different from int?

Comment: You really should read [Objective-C Programming Language introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C programmers don't like typing, so we do it like this:

```
@interface Person : NSObject
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic, assign) int age;
@end

@implementation Person
@end
```

You may want to start by reading Apple's [Objective-C Programming Language introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html).

Answer (score 0):

in ObjectiveC the way to refer to 'this' is 'self'

Answer (score 0):

You have this in ObjectiveC because you are using C style variables. If you declare that variables as [ObjectiveC](http://www.cocoacast.com/cocoacast/?q=node/103) properties and use the correct synthesize instruction:

```
@property (int) age;

@synthesize age;
```

Then you can refer to them through `self.age`

```
self.age = age;
```

in the implementation file. This will internally call the `-(void)setAge:(int)age` method and the `-(int) age` methods which will be defined automatically.

Finally since an ObjectiveC object is nothing more than a pointer to a C struct you can access variables by skipping ObjectiveC by using the syntax to refer to fields of a pointer to a struct: `self->age = age`

Comment: Getting an error. In my interface I have -(void) setAge:(int) age; and then in my implementation I did the code like you said but it says local declaration of age is hiding instance variable